# How to create separate action/view that adds Book to Author

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have implemented a testapp with model "Author" has-many "Books" by following  http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised. I am using only one simple relation in my example, nothing else.

The app works perfectly, I can add and delete Books dynamically to an Author using "link_to_add_fields" etc. Save, modify, delete works as they should.

The form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@author) do |author_form| %>
<%= author_form.input :name %><br />
  <%= author_form.input :born %><br />
  <h1>Books by this author</h1>
  <!-- will Assume @author.books (somehow...) -->
  <%= author_form.simple_fields_for :books do |book_fields| %>
    <%= render partial: "book_fields", locals: {f: book_fields} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Book", author_form, :books %>
  <%= author_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I also have a partial "_book_fields.html.erb" which is used from both the Edit view and the JS-code.

```
<fieldset class="book">
    <%= f.input :title %><br />
    <%= f.input :pages %><br />
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

I also have a Cover field where I upload a picture using Paperclip but I removed that for brevity.

The problem I have is that now I want to create a "Add single book to author"-action/view. I can't wrap my head around how the partial should be used.

Lets say I have an Author-action which looks up an Author-id, and creates an empty Book (using `@author.books.build` ?) how do I show such a form in the view so that the only action possible is to ADD another book to the Author.books array? Can I use the existing partial?

Lets say I would want another separate action/view with Remove book from Author, how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

To have an expressive and DRYed code I:

First, rename that partial to be reused, to choose a name is difficult.

Second, let's say you have two actions in `AuthorsController`: `new_one` and `new_many`. Names are difficult here. Then, you would have `app/views/authors/new_one.html.erb` and `app/views/authors/new_many.html.erb`

Third, I would call your renamed partial like this:

```
# new_one
= render partial: 'renamed_partial', locals: { link_to_add: false }

# new_many
= render partial: 'renamed_partial', locals: { link_to_add: true }
```

And your renamed partial would change:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@author) do |author_form| %>
<%= author_form.input :name %><br />
  <%= author_form.input :born %><br />
  <h1>Books by this author</h1>
  <!-- will Assume @author.books (somehow...) -->
  <%= author_form.simple_fields_for :books do |book_fields| %>
    <%= render partial: "book_fields", locals: {f: book_fields} %>
  <% end %>

  <%#### Here is the change! ####%>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Book", author_form, :books if link_to_add %>


  <%= author_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I forgot, you are right, you should use `@author.books.build` to add a new book.

Comment: This looks like the proper "rails" way of solving it. I will test it as soon as I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

An **alternative** to **juanpastas** answer, it's more code here. After this you get a custom action to add a book for the author.

in **authors/show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Add book', add_book_author_path(@author) %>
```

in **app/controllers/authors_controller.rb**

```
def add_book
 @author = Author.find(params[:id])
 @book = @author.books.new
end
```

in **routes.rb**

```
resources :authors do
  member do
    get 'add_book'
  end
end
```

in **app/views/authors/add_book.html.erb** you can render the book `_form.html.erb` with `render partial: /books/form` or write your own form:

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**edit related to comment below**

```
irb(main):001:0> user = User.last
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 4, email: "vcina@bk.ru", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$Rw3x2SadeYdubWa1uYc7oeIJnLe3B8nbjYcw0iPbbnZO...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2013-06-05 13:51:54", updated_at: "2013-06-05 13:51:54", first_name: "Vcina", last_name: "Dmitrii", role: "user", approved: false>
```

here the user is loaded into user variable, pretend it's your author. Next we'll want to add a new company for that user, pretend company is a book in your case:

```
irb(main):002:0> user.companies.new
=> #<Company id: nil, user_id: 4, responsible_id: nil, name: nil, company_branch_id: nil, company_source_id: nil, client_category_id: nil, client_type_id: nil, client_at: nil, phone: nil, fax: nil, email: nil, skype: nil, website: nil, facebook: nil, bank_req: nil, fisc_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, client_status_id: nil, number_employees: nil, organizational_form_id: nil, marked_to_remove: false>
```

have a look at `user_id` in the logs, it's the id of the user that we loaded before, and all that's left to do is to fill in the fields for the title of the book or whatever you have there and press submit.

On submit, the action `create` will be called that will create a book using params of book that you'll send with the request.

Comment: OK this seems to be a simple enough solution. A change in the controller though: it should be `@book = @author.books.build`, right?

Comment: not really, it by saying @author.books.new it already knows who is the author of the book. I'll give you an exemple with user and companies in couple of minutes.

Comment: I dont understand. My interpretation is: If I use `@author.books.build` the new Book will have Book.author_id set automatically. Isnt that alot better than using `@author.books.new(:author_id => @author.id)`? It is also added to the books array, which new does not. To persist it I must call `@author.save`. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: `@author.books.build` I would use in case if I want to add more books at once for that author, if only one there is no need to use `builder`.

Comment: `@author.books.new(title: "Nice book")` will return you `#<Company id: nil, author_id: 4, title: Nice book>` and on save it will create this book with the author of id 4.

Comment: You said in your question that you want to add one book to the author, that's what my code does by calling `@author.books.new` and you don't have to write `:author_id => @author.id` inside of the params, I gave you an exemple of mine with companies, do you see anywhere in company where I write `:user_id => @user.id` ?